# How to use a pointer to a vector variable in C++？

Tags: c++

The example code:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string>* v;
    v->push_back("hello");
    v->push_back("world");
    v->push_back("!");
    for(vector<string>::iterator it = v->begin(); it != v->end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I use `vector<string> v`, it's OK.

But why segmentation fault when I use `vector<string>* v`?

Comment: Because you don't read the warnings of your compiler! It will tell you that you used an uninitialized variable (`v`).

Comment: It's a pointer... It points to some memory that you should have allocated (on the heap or on the stack if you are using a pointer to a local objec). Here, the said pointer is uninitialized so it can point to whatever address

Comment: `v` is a pointer that can point to a `std::vector<std::string>`. But you can't do anything with it until you point it to an actual `std::vector<std::string>`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code isnt working is because you dont initialise your pointer.

Try this instead:

```
vector<string>* v = new vector<string>();
```

Also, make sure to call

```
delete v;
```

When you don't need your vector anymore.

Comment: Also make sure if you really need dynamic memory. Most likely you want `vector<string> v` instead.

Comment: And do not forget to `delete` it.

Comment: And then do not forget to remove `new` and `delete` and replace them with a smart pointer.